# Three-pane split view interface on iPad landscape mode

Tags: ios, ipad, cocoa-touch, layout, uisplitviewcontroller

iOS Notes and Mail apps have a three-pane split view interface on iPad landscape mode. How can I create such interface? I checked `UISplitViewController` but it made only two panes (master and detail). Can somebody please enlighten me how to create the leftmost pane?

[image: Three-pane split view interface example]

Answer (score 2):

It's done using custom layout. You have root view controller that loads three other view controllers into three container views. That is all.

Answer (score 1):

Starting iOS 14, you [can use](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisplitviewcontroller) `UISplitViewController.Style.tripleColumn` (`UISplitViewControllerStyleTripleColumn` in Objective-C) for a three-column layout with a supplementary view:

[image]